# fmincon with lower bound fails, even though solution is at initial point

Tags: matlab, minimization

I'm trying to minimize a non-linear objective function (my actual function is much more complicated than that, but I found that even this simple function illustrates the point), where I know that minimum is obtained at the initial point `x0`:

```
fun = @(x) x(1)^2+x(2)^2;
x0 = [0 0];
lb1 = [0 0];
lb2 = [-1 -1];

[xc1 fvalc1] = fmincon(fun, x0, [],[],[],[], lb1, [Inf Inf])
```

Which outputs:

```
>> xc1 = 1.0e-03 * [0.6457    0.6457]
>> fvalc1 = 8.3378e-07
```

However, both using a different lower bound or using `fminsearch` instead work correctly:

```
[xc2 fvalc2] = fmincon(fun, x0, [],[],[],[], lb2, [Inf Inf])
>> xc2 = [0     0]
>> fvalc2 =  0

[xs fvals] = fminsearch(fun, x0)
>> xs =  [0     0]
>> fvals =   0
```

What goes wrong in the first `fmincon` call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can diagnose this using the `output` output argument as specified in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)

```
[xc1, fvalc1, ~, output] = fmincon(fun, x0, [],[],[],[], lb1, [Inf Inf])
```

The value `output.stepsize` is the final step size taken in the iterative solving process. In this case:

```
output.stepsize
>> ans = 6.586e-4
```

The estimated minima was at `x = [6.457e-4, 6.457e-4]` and the lower bounds you've permitted are `[0 0]`, so the solver is not permitted to take another step! Another step would give `x = [-1.29e-5, -1.29e-5]` which is outside of the boundaries.

When you allow the lower bounds to be `[-1, -1]` the solver can over-shoot the minimum and approach it from all directions.

---

Moreover, we can use the `options` input to get *even better* insight!

```
options.Display = 'iter';
[xc1, fvalc1, ~, output] = fmincon(fun, x0, [],[],[],[], lb1, [Inf Inf], [], options);
```

Printed to the command window we see this:

```
Your initial point x0 is not between bounds lb and ub; FMINCON
shifted x0 to strictly satisfy the bounds.

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
    0       3    1.960200e+00    0.000e+00    9.900e-01
    1       6    1.220345e-02    0.000e+00    8.437e-01    1.290e+00
    2       9    4.489374e-02    0.000e+00    4.489e-02    1.014e-01
    3      12    1.172900e-02    0.000e+00    1.173e-02    1.036e-01
    4      15    3.453565e-03    0.000e+00    3.454e-03    4.953e-02
    5      18    1.435780e-03    0.000e+00    1.436e-03    2.088e-02
    6      21    4.659097e-04    0.000e+00    4.659e-04    1.631e-02
    7      24    2.379407e-04    0.000e+00    2.379e-04    6.160e-03
    8      27    6.048934e-05    0.000e+00    6.049e-05    7.648e-03
    9      30    1.613884e-05    0.000e+00    1.614e-05    3.760e-03
   10      33    5.096660e-06    0.000e+00    5.097e-06    1.760e-03
   11      36    2.470360e-06    0.000e+00    2.470e-06    6.858e-04
   12      39    8.337765e-07    0.000e+00    8.338e-07    6.586e-04
```

**So your `x0` is invalid!** This is why the solver doesn't return the result with 1 iteration and lower bounds of `[0 0]`.

`fminsearch` also works for the same reason - you've not imposed a lower bound on which the solution sits.

Comment: Why is `x0=[0 0]` not within the lower bound `lb=[0 0]`? No matter the floating point representation, it should be within.

Comment: It is not *between* the bounds, i.e. `lb < x0 < ub`. You can have a solution which sits on the boundary (although as you've seen above, the step size will dictate how close you get), but the intial guess has to be between them for the solver to work as I assume it's based on 3 *unique* points. Notably, the default method is `'interior-point'`, the clue is in the name.